# unable build project in STM32 AC6

Tags: eclipse-cdt, stm32

While i am building a project in STM32 AC6 software, I got the message 'building finished', but i am not able to run or debug due to the missing of binaries.The error code is as follows.Please help me

arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
make: *** [startup/startup_stm32f334x8.o] Error 1
startup/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'startup/startup_stm32f334x8.o' failed
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [src/syscalls.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:24: recipe for target 'src/syscalls.o' failed

Answer (score 0):

check that your project path does not contain any signs "-" or spaces " ", it is mostly the raison.